# unexpected PREG_MATCH behavior

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Heey,

I really don't get what the problem is. I execute the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$tomatch='abc 6e t/m 8e uur vervalt';
var_dump($tomatch);
var_dump(preg_match('/([1-9])e t\/m ([1-9])e/',$tomatch));
?>
```

Which gives me the following answer:

> string 'abc 6e t/m 8e uur vervalt' *(length=25)*
>   int 0

However, inserting the same values in http://regexpal.com/ will give a match.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: JavaScript regex and PCRE are not the same dialect.

Comment: That's not the problem; when I run the same code on my server it works fine..

Comment: looks fine to me, I am reading it a million time again..

Comment: Hmm, yeah, just tested and it matches it for me as well.  Your inputs must not be what you think they are.  `php -r "$tomatch = 'abc 6e t/m 8e uur vervalt'; var_dump(preg_match('/([1-9])e t\/m ([1-9])e/',$tomatch));"` outputs `int(1)`

Comment: Looking at the code in your post, `$tomatch` contains non-breaking spaces, but the pattern is looking for normal spaces.

Comment: @Corbin not the input, $tomatch is statically assigned takes no value.

Comment: I'm sorry, on my production server as well as my test server the code returns no match. Is there any setting which could cause this behavior?

Comment: Try this just in case: `var_dump(preg_match('/([1-9])e t\/m ([1-9])e/','abc 6e t/m 8e uur vervalt'))`

Comment: add this line and run the code, then show us the output..

Comment: To the people down voting: this answer is correct.  The spaces are not normal spaces in the post, but rather the character code 0xA0.

Comment: @AhmedJolani The input apparently isn't the problem.  Well, not the method of input (as I thought it was).  The problem is that the standard space character wasn't used.  See DCoder's answer.

Comment: @AhmedJolani This does indeed return int(1). However I still don't get what the problem is. It has something to do with the scope of the variable?

Comment: @Boelensman1 no I don't think so, if this is exactly the code you wrote there should be no error.

Comment: What would the correct regex be? When using the whitespace modifier and making the regex
/([1-9])e\st\/m\s([1-9])e/<br> it still returns no match.

Comment: @Boelensman1 try copying your code from here and paste back to your test page and run it.

Comment: @Beolensman1 The easiest approach would be to `str_replace(chr(0xa0), ' ', $str)` and then run the regex on it.

Comment: @AhmedJolani After copying it does work, but that doesn't fix the problem. I think Corbin was right, because making the imput$tomatch='abc 6e#0xA0t/m 8e uur vervalt'; still looks the same in html (the first var_dump), but does not match.

Comment: @Corbin Thanks, quite simple but working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Beolensman1 The easiest approach would be to str_replace(chr(0xa0), '
>   ', $str) and then run the regex on it.

This comment by Corbin answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$tomatch='abc 6e t/m 8e uur vervalt';
var_dump($tomatch);
preg_match_all('/([1-9])e t\/m ([1-9])e/',$tomatch,$matches));

print_r($matches);
```